# How to count few category (not count row) using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a table like this:

```
 country   province   city   people
 __________________________________
 country1  province1  city1   200 
 country1  province1  city2   150 
 country1  province2  city3   350
 country2  province3  city4   75
```

I need to show how many countries, how many provinces, how many cities and how many people I have. Then I need to show how many people in each city, each province and each country.

I already tried `Count(Distinct)` but it cannot be used with a partition.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly you want number of countries, number of province, number of city and total population right ? If thats the case for all number of <cities/province/city> do count() and for total peoples do sum()

Comment: Please shown the full query you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `GROUP BY` with `GROUPING SETS` will help you:

```
SELECT
  --GROUPING_ID(country,province,city),
  CASE GROUPING_ID(country,province,city)
    WHEN 7 THEN 'total'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'country total - '+country
    WHEN 1 THEN 'province total - '+province
    ELSE 'city - '+city
  END row_title,
  country,
  province,
  city,
  COUNT(DISTINCT province) province_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT city) city_count,
  SUM(people) people_count
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
      (country,province,city),
      (country,province),
      (country),
      ()
    )
ORDER BY country,province,city
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(country varchar(20),province varchar(20),city varchar(20),people int)

INSERT YourTable(country,province,city,people)VALUES
('country1','province1','city1',200),
('country1','province1','city2',150),
('country1','province2','city3',350),
('country2','province3','city4',75)
```

Also try to use the following:

```
SELECT column_name,value
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT province) [province count],
      COUNT(DISTINCT city) [city count],
      SUM(people) [people count]
    FROM YourTable
  ) q UNPIVOT(value FOR column_name IN([province count],[city count],[people count])) u
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, Andi. Count(Distinct...) is the right way to go.

If you want to know how many countries there are, use:

```
select count(distinct(country)) from yourtable;
```

How many provinces? Counting cities is similar to province.

```
select count(distinct(province)) from yourtable;
```

How many people?

```
select sum(people) from yourtable;
```

For people, you cannot just take a count. You will have to sum up all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach to get counts as you desired:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(country varchar(20),province varchar(20),city varchar(20),people int)

INSERT #YourTable(country,province,city,people)VALUES
('country1','province1','city1',200),
('country1','province1','city2',150),
('country1','province2','city3',350),
('country2','province3','city4',75)

SELECT 'Distinct Countries' AS type, COUNT(DISTINCT country) from #YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Distinct province' AS type, COUNT(DISTINCT province) from #YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Distinct City' AS type, COUNT(DISTINCT city) from #YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('Distinct ', Country,' ', province,' ', city), count(people)
FROM #YourTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP(country, province, city)
```

Answer (score 0):

This following script will return your all results in a single row. But if you want each results in a separate row, you may need to use UNION to achieve the expected result set.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Country) [Number of Country],
COUNT(DISTINCT Province) [Number of Province],
COUNT(DISTINCT City) [Number of City],
SUM(People) [Total People]
FROM (
    VALUES
            ('country1','province1','city1',200),
            ('country1','province1','city2',150 ),
            ('country1','province2','city3',350),
            ('country2','province3','city4',75)
    ) 
    V([Country],[Province],City,People);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need `count(distinct)` for the population.  How about this?

```
select country, province, city, sum(people) 
from t
group by grouping sets ( (country, province, city), (country, province), (country) );
```

I see no evidence in your sample data that people are being double counted.

To count the numbers for each group requires something like this:

```
select count(distinct country) as num_countries,
       count(distinct country + ':' + province) as num_provinces,
       count(distinct country + ':' + province + ':' + city) as num_cities
```

SQL Server does not allow multiple arguments for `count(distinct)`.